# Assigning a String " value in java

Tags: java, string, special-characters

I have a string in java.

```
String textQualifier;
```

I want to assign it the value `"`
how can I do it in java. I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: `"\""`, you need to escape it.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before. In order to adding some chars like **"** to an string those must be escaped

## Example:

```
String myString = "\"";
```

Note the use of the **escape sign** \ here...

Now your string is assigned correctly...